# Finding the printer's IP address

Tags: printing

I've installed a new printer on the server and on CUPS, I checked the 'Share printers connected to this system', but not 'Allow printing from the Internet'.

The client finds the printer and configures it with a

```
dnssd://printer-location._ipp._tcp.local/cups
```

But the printer is Idle - "The printer is not responding."

I've read that to install the (any) printer correctly the IP address is needed.

Anybody has any idea how to obtain the IP address of a printer? My printer is not listed in [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) (yet).

**Edit** For ipp to work, do I have to set 'Allow printing from the Internet' on the server?
Also, Is it possible to allow only a specific client per IP or MAC?

**Solved** So easy. I forgot to check the 'Show printers shared by other systems' on the client machine. I choose the printer I was looking for and bingo! No need for the IP after all.

Comment: The printer is connected to the 'server', and I don't find any ethernet connector on the printer, so... I'll need to configure the server to accept the print jobs of the client ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ip address of the printer is going to be the same as the server it is connected to.

```
ifconfig
iwconfig
```

If it is a network printer, not connected to another computer, but directly to your LAN, either it will display on the printer menu (menus vary by printer/model) or you can get the ip address from your router.

Comment: I'll try to connect through the server, and check back.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that your network printer is using DHCP to get it's IP address. If you have a router, there should be an aspect to the interface that will show you the leases that are being used on your network. A little detective work should allow you to determine what the host name of your printer is (process of elimination) along with the IP address. Your printer should also have a label with the MAC address on it which should further help you identify that IP given to your printer. I

I inherited a printer and didn't know the IP and this is how I figured it out. I then gave the printer a static IP address and put it on a label on the front of it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a network printer it will have its own IP address.  Depending on the printer type there will be a 'service' button that you need to press.  On HP it is the 'checkmark' button I seem to recall.

Other manufacturers might only allow you to check it as you switch on the printer (by pressing a combination of buttons at power up).  Best place to look is online documentation if you don't have the owner's manual.

Press the appropriate button and the printer will print out a set of details about its own settings including the IP address etc.

This will allow you to access the printer's internal web server.

Comment: No, not a network printer. I checked and it doesn't have autonomous network capabilities. No IP address on the service page either...