# Printer scanner driver for Epson Workforce WF-5320

Tags: unity, drivers, scanner

Having trouble with setup here.  I have 64-bit Ubuntu Unity 12.10.

First I ran

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc
```

Then I clicked `accept` on the Epson website [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=24992&DSCCHK=6c664adcc21899820883bad3becd133e61e94348).  I downloaded `iscan-data_1.25.0-1_all.deb` and installed it with

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.25.0-1_all.deb
```

Next, after some trial and error (because there were several .deb files to choose from, but only one would install successfully), I downloaded `iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` and ran

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
```

Next, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209795/epson-xp-605-printer-driver-for-ubuntu), I ran

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
```

and inserted a line below in the Examples section: `net xxx`, where for `xxx` I inserted my [best guess](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/ip-ubuntu-54795.html) at the IP address of the printer.

Finally, from my Dash Home, I typed "epson", and a new application `Image Scan for Linux!" appeared.  However, when I try to launch this, I only get a message that says "Could not send command to scanner.  Check the scanner's status".  Now what?  The scanner just worked fine a moment ago through it's connection with a windows machine.

I wonder if I have the wrong IP address for my printer.  Including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87540/finding-the-printers-ip-address), I have not yet found an explanation of how to identify the IP address of my printer in a fully straightforward way.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. So others can get. you can install mtink for printer maintenance.`sudo apt-get install mtink`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just gone through the process of installing the Epson iScan software following the recipe in the original question. There is just one stage missing to enable network access of the Epson scanner, to install `iscan-network-nt`.

The full recipe is as follows. For 32-bit machines the architecture labels will of course need changing to `i386`:

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.25.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
```

There are two entries to change in the `epkowa.conf` file, one for the network ip address (which you can get from the printer itself or from your router), and one to specify preference for the document feeder (although the latter seems to be brain-dead). After editing `epkowa.conf` it should contain the following lines somewhere:

```
net your.printer.ip.here
...
option prefer-adf
```

Not only does this enable the Epson scanner software, it allows XSane and Simple Scan also to correctly locate and interact with the scanner.

Comment: It worked!  The hardest part was figuring out the printer IP address.  It still seems like there should be a simple command to reveal the IP addresses of all printers on the network ... that would make a great addition to the solution, or perhaps re-posting as a separate question.

Comment: @zkurtz There are several ways to get the printer's ip address. In my case I like to set it in the router, so it will always be the same. Another way is to go to the printer and get it to print out it's wireless settings, and a third way is to check the ip when you use the `Add Printer` tool's `Network Printer` option; it searches the lan and reports the ip addresses of any printers it finds.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, almost all the **All-In-One printers** *does not need* additional drivers to be installed. Drivers are automatically loaded by the following applications.

You can run the scanner with application **Simple Scan**

And the Printer with application **Printers**

Comment: At the simplistic level this is correct, but to make use of scanner features you need the proprietary drivers. Similarly, when you add the printer with the Printers tool the correct software for the drivers is detected and downloaded, so it is not strictly correct that additional drivers are not needed.