# How to install a Dell printer on Ubuntu

Tags: printing, dell

It's not always as easy as it should be to install an Dell printer on Ubuntu, even when it is supported.

Dell have a how-to page, but it's very generic: http://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/audhs1/SLN79181/cs

Sometimes, the biggest problem is finding the drivers. They aren't always accessible from the printer support page. For example, http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/audhs1/product-support/product/dell-e514dw-printer/drivers only has Windows drivers, no Linux drivers, even though the e514dw supports both Ubuntu and RedHat.

And even once you've found the drivers, it's not quite click to install.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on the E514dw. I hope other Dell printers are similar, but no promises.

The first challenge is finding the drivers.

The important thing, for me, was to give up on searching Dell's site, and turn to Google: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=dell+E514dw+ubuntu

That returned: http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/audhs1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=FV8XM

You can download a zip file from there that contains 4 drivers:

- e514dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
- e514dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.rpm
- e514dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
- e514dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.rpm

First, extract e514dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb from the zip file.

And install it, for example:

- dpkg -i e514dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

If you want to connect via usb, you should be done.

If you also want to connect wirelessly, there are a few more steps.

You might be able to skip this next step, but I also installed: e514dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

- dpkg -i e514dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

Then use system-config-printer to add the printer as a network printer.

Run the printer configuration wizard:
    system-config-printer

Then:

- click Add
- click on Network Printer
- wait a few 10s of seconds, and your printer should be detected
- click on your printer, and click Forward
- optional: set Host to your printers IP address
- click Local Driver, then click Forward
- make sure Dell is selected, then click Forward
- make sure E514dw for CPUS is selected, then click Forward
- optional: update the Name, Description and/or Location
- click Apply
- optional: print a test page.

If you didn't explicitly enter the IP address, the print system will now think your printer is called DELL5C5DFA.

To fix that, you can either edit /etc/hosts and add an entry for DELL5C5DFA, or can go back into system-config-printer and change the Device URI.

Either way, if you don't know your printer's IP address, you need to find it. I used nmap -O, but there are some other, maybe simpler, suggestions here: [Finding the printer's IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87540/finding-the-printers-ip-address)

To test your connection without having to print a test page, you can check 'ink/toner levels'